# For Loop delay not working Android

Tags: java, android

I am a newbie to android development so bear with me. I have scoured the site and implemented several suggested answers but I am still running into a problem. I want to iterate through an object array and display the contents of the array with delay to allow user interaction(The user gets to say if the object and the text displayed is what they were looking for by clicking on a yes or no button). My objects however display last first and then start zooming real fast in a seemingly endless loop. Here is the method I call to load the images:

```
private void displayInstructions() {
    for (Emergency_Instructions instruction : instructions) {
        final Emergency_Instructions instruction2 = instruction;

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
        {
        public void run() {
            displayimages(instruction2.getStep(), instruction2.getStepImage());
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);           
        }
    }, 5000);
}

void displayimages(String text, Bitmap image)
{
    instructiontext.setText(text);
    instructionbmp.setImageBitmap(image);
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: First time posting, been edited

Comment: I'd never seen a question like that. Thank you for the fine humour! :D

Comment: you welcome,glad to put smile on your face this fine friday. Any assistance you can offer to the funny question will still be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create multiple `Handler`s where you need only one.  You tell each one to post a `Runnable` to the current thread's message queue, to be run after the same delay.  That delay expires at pretty much the same time for all the tasks, so they are then executed one right after another, as fast as the queue can go.  Each of those tasks also posts a message via the handler, to be run after the same delay.  Once that delay expires, that will produce a second group of messages posted rapidly one right after the other, as fast as the device can go.

If you just want to schedule what is effectively a slide show, you might do it like this:

```
private void displayInstructions() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    int delay = 0;
    int step = 5000;

    for (Emergency_Instructions instruction : instructions) {
        final Emergency_Instructions instruction2 = instruction;

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                displayimages(instruction2.getStep(), instruction2.getStepImage());
                // handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
            }
        }, delay);

        delay += step;
    }
}
```

Note there that each task is posted with a larger delay than the last -- this is a delay with respect to when the message it *posted*, not with respect to when the preceding message was displayed.

With that said, I'm doubtful that this is really what you want to do, or at least that it is *all* you want to do.  As it stands, this approach will cause all the messages to be displayed (eventually) regardless of any user interaction.  At minimum, you will probably want to provide for subsequent messages to be canceled in the event that the user accepts one, or cancels the overall operation.

Comment: thank you so much! This definitely gets me over the 'wall' that I was encountering! How would I cancel the thread if a user clicked on the yes button indicating that their choice had displayed? But this info helps a lot, thanks